# How to display associate arrays in a table php

Tags: php, arrays

Right i will start by showing you the code as it will make sense quickly

```
 private static $cases = [
    '100' => [
        'id' => '1',
        'case_no' => '1',
        'name' => 'First Case'  
    ],
    '101' => [
        'id' => '2',
        'case_no' => '2',
        'name' => 'Second Case'   
    ],
];
```

Now i want a table with 3 columns and two rows.

The column headers should be id case_no and name.

```
     foreach($results as $key => $value){
          echo '<tr>';
          echo "<td>";
          echo 
          echo "</td>";
          echo "<td>";
          echo 
          echo "</td>";
          echo "<td>";
          echo 
          echo "</td>";
          echo '</tr>';
        }
```

what do i need to put in there to make this happen?

EDIT::

In my model i find a specific case by the $case_no someone searches for.

```
public static function findByCaseNo($case_no)
{
    foreach (self::$cases as $case) {
        if (strcasecmp($case['case_no'], $case_no) === 0) {
            return new static($case);
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Then my Controller send back to the view results as that specific case

```
   return $this->render('search', [
                'model' => $model,
                'dataProvider' => $model->findAll(),
                'results' => $case,
                'case_no' => $case_no
            ]);
```

Comment: What's the relationship between `$cases` and `$results`?

Comment: @MarkBaker ive updated my question for you

Answer (score 1):

You either need two loops or call it key by key

```
echo "<table>";
foreach($cases as $key=> $value){
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>".$value['id']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$value['case_no']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$value['name']."</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```